# Installing Ubuntu on a Chromebook without a dual-boot

Tags: boot, chromebook

I am looking at getting a Chromebook but I don't like limitations on my computer systems and looking to get back into a heavier Linux work load. Has anyone install a complete version of Ubuntu on a Chromebook without having a dual-boot setup? If so is it just simply booting from a USB drive and installing the OS or is there more coding involved?  I am looking at some of the Asus Chromebooks.

Thank You in advance for any help or suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I found these results online:

---

*Swapnil  Bhartiya* - November 17, 2014

## How to Easily Install Ubuntu on Chromebook with Crouton

#### How to Install Ubuntu

**#Step 1: Back up your data**

Before we start poking around, please ensure that you have a back-up of your data. Since all of your data is synced to Google Server, you actually don’t have to worry about losing any data. The only data that you must make a back-up of is the ‘Download’ folder because the content of this folder is not synced. Once you have taken the back-up, it’s also a fail-safe plan to create a restore USB of ChromeOS, in case something goes wrong and you need to re-install ChromeOS.

**#Step 2: Create a restore image for Chrome OS**

Since Crouton is not going to wipe your Chrome OS, there is no risk of corrupting your Chrome OS. It’s always a good idea to keep a restore image of your OS.

Install Chromebook recovery utility from the Chrome web store. Open the app and follow the instructions to create the recovery drive. It’s an easy three-step, click next process. All you need is working Internet and a USB drive with at least 4GB space.

Once the recovery disk is created, unplug it and follow the following steps.

**#Step 3: Enable developer mode**

In order to install your own operating system on Chromebooks, you have to enable the developer mode. It’s extremely easy to do and is very well documented by Google. The latest Chromebooks use a combination of keys to enter the developer mode, whereas older devices have a 
physical switch. Different devices have different locations for the switch, so please Google your device to find the location of the switch and flip it. If you are on the latest Chromebook then you can enable the developer mode by holding **Esc + Refresh** keys and then push the ‘power’ button. The recovery screen will show a scary warning. Just ignore it and let Chrome OS wipe your data. The process can take up to 15 minutes, so don’t turn off your Chromebook.

Also keep in mind that once Chrome OS is reinstalled you will continue to see this warning every time you boot your system, as long as the developer mode is enabled. However, it won’t wipe the data every time. You can simply hit **Ctrl+d** to quickly boot into Chrome OS (don’t do it this time while Chrome OS is preparing your system for developer mode).

**Step #4: Let’s install Crouton**

1- Log into your Chromebook and open the [GitHub page of Crouton](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/blob/master/README.md) and [download the latest script.](https://goo.gl/fd3zc)

Check the download folder to see if crouton is downloaded.

2- Open the terminal in Chromebook (yes, there is now a terminal in Chromebook! by hitting **Alt+Ctrl+t**

3 -Type this command to open shell: `shell`

4- Now we are going to install Ubuntu. There are several desktop environments available including KDE Plasma, Unity and Xfce. Unity can be quite heavy for Chromebook hardware and xfce is way too plain for my taste, so I am going to install KDE Plasma.

`sudo sh ~/Downloads/crouton -t kde`

(If you don’t want KDE, then you can replace kde with xfce, or unity )

For example:

`sudo sh ~/Downloads/crouton -t xfce`

We have not encrypted the chroot, if you want to encrypt it then add -e parameter to the command above:

`sudo sh -e ~/Downloads/crouton -t kde`

If you are installing it on a Chromebook with touchscreen then also add the ‘touch’ parameter:

`sudo sh -e ~/Downloads/crouton -t touch,kde`

Since the script will download Ubuntu from the Internet, depending on your broadband speed, it may take a while, so go and grab some Indian chai or coffee. With my 150Mbps download speed it took me around 18 minutes. Once the install is finished Crouton will ask you to enter the user-name and UNIX password for it - which will be used to perform administrative tasks in Kubuntu.

Now you can start Plasma by running the following command in shell:

`sudo startkde`

If you installed xfce then run:

`sudo startxfce4`

You will be greeted by the KDE greeter.

#### **Fine tune Ubuntu**

The install will be bare-minimum and won’t come with the applications that are packed by distributions, but you can easily install applications from Konsole / terminal. It’s also a good idea to update the system.

`sudo apt-get update` `sudo apt-get upgrade` `sudo apt-get install`

I installed all that I needed - LibreOffice, Sublime Text, Chrome browser (so I can watch Netflix), GIMP, VLC, etc.

#### **How to switch between Chrome OS and Ubuntu?**

To go back to Chrome OS, and keep KDE running, use this key combination **Alt+Ctrl+Shift+Back.** To come back to Kubuntu from Chrome OS, use this combination:**Alt+Ctrl+Shift+Forward**. You can find the back/forward keys on the top row of the keyboard.

When you log out of KDE, it exits you from Chroot and you will have to again run the `sudo startkde` command to start Plasma or the desktop that you have installed.

---

Source  - https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/795730-how-to-easily-install-ubuntu-on-chromebook-with-crouton

- https://youtu.be/2a_rq6bYR3M